# Jhipster display other value when insert connected entites

Tags: jhipster

How to display other value when I want to add new Prelection
[image]

But when I have to choose Event, there is Event Id. How to change it to name? 
Could you give me an example, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you got asked by JHipster entity sub generator when you created Prelection entity and added a relationship to Event:

> When you display this relationship with Angular, which field from 'Event' do you want to use? (id)

Just enter the field name from the related entity you want to use for presentation (by default it's "id").

For your existing entity Prelection, you can edit `.jhipster/Prelection.json` and change `otherEntityField`:

```
    {
        "relationshipName": "event",
        "otherEntityName": "event",
        "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
        "relationshipValidateRules": [
            "required"
        ],
        "otherEntityField": "name"
    },
```

and then re-generate your entity with `yo jhipster:entity Prelection`.